# Adding activity in Android app made by Unity w/ Vuforia

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I've made a simple Unity AR app with Vuforia and then exported that into Android Studio project, so I can configure something inside the application itself.

What I'm trying to configure is to make the start screen of the generated application **not to be** a Camera (it's by-default so if you make .apk from Unity+Vuforia), but some other screen, in which by clicking on the button, the AR functional will appear (the Camera from the previous sentence).

And I can't achieve that, no matter what I try. I'm adding new Activity and after that I get the whole bunch of errors, from 'cannot resolve symbol R' to 'cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity'.

I'm absolutely new to all this tools and for sure asking dumb question, but if someone could give me a hint or whether it's possible to do and ideally, how :) I would very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that create a empty scene in Unity, and load the AR scene by android when you need.

**FirstScene.cs** in Unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FirstScene : MonoBehaviour {

    public void loadGame() {
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("ARScene");
    }
}
```

**YourActivity.java** in android

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectNameYouBindFirstScene", "loadGame", "");
```